# Producing a list that can be sorted

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a piece of code, which is a function called within a loop over a dictionary, it is as follows:

```
hope = []
seconds = []
hope.append(self.date)
for those in hope:
    date = those
    pattern = '%m/%d/%Y'
    epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date, pattern)))
    seconds.append(epoch)
    print seconds
```

I am getting results like

```
[1505084400]
[1500850800]
[1509926400]
[1496617200]
[1492383600]
[1488758400]
[1499036400]
[1511136000]
[1511136000]
…
```

But I want the results of seconds to be like:

```
[1505084400,1500850800,1509926400,1496617200,1492383600,1488758400,1499036400,1511136000,1511136000.....]
```

So that the sort and sorted functions will work on it.

Comment: Your `for` loop has always exactly one iteration, since `hope` is a list of length one.  Seems pretty pointless to me, but I have no idea what this code is supposed to do instead.

Comment: Sounds to me like `seconds` needs to be a member variable or a parameter because each time you call the method you are creating a new `seconds` list.

Comment: Next time, please post the complete class definition.  without the init we are forced to guess at certain parts of what your code is doing.  I of course assume your using a class because there is a reference to self in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the print statement out of the for loop and maintain the state of the lists:

```
class someclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.hope = []
        self.seconds = []
    def appendtoseconds(self):
        self.hope.append(self.date)
        for those in self.hope:
            date = those
            pattern = '%m/%d/%Y'
            epoch = int(time.mktime(time.strptime(date, pattern)))
            self.seconds.append(epoch)
        print self.seconds
```

Comment: `self.seconds` will grow quadratically with this approach, since `self.hope` is reiterated every time `appendtoseconds()` is called.

Comment: True, but since we have no idea of what he is trying to accomplish besides building a sortable persistent list, it still reasonably answers the question asked